# How to access returned json data of php objects

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have created a large data structure in php which I send back to a jQuery "post" request.
The data arrives in the following format

```
"{\"event\":{\"id\":\"5\",\"title\":\"Test Event\",\"event_ref\":\"TEST\",\"approval\":\"na\",\
```

The data is sent back as a double quoted string with the double quotes escaped. The url directory markers are also escaped.
The above is just a small part of the string which is returned.

- If I alert(data) I get the string displayed in the alert box.
- If I alert(data[0]) I get a " displayed
- If I alert(data[event]) I get undefined displayed.

Generally, I can not use either dot notation or array notation to access the data.
I suspect I need to get rid of the outer enclosing double quotes and un-escape it.
The data is an array, some of the items are simple values, some are objects and some are arrays of objects.

How do I access the returned data?
The structure will allways be the same although some of the objects will often be missing.

The js code is:

```
//  The login button
$("#loginButton").click(    function(){
var username = $('input#login-username').val();     
var password = $('input#login-passwd').val();       
    alert("Login button clicked with username/password: "+username+" / "+password);
$.post(
    $_interface,
    { option: 'login', userID: username, pwd: password },
    function(response){
        if (response) {
//              alert("Response = true");
            $.post(
                $_interface,
                { option: 'superGlobalValues', target: 'session' },
                function(data){
                alert(data);
                    }
                );
            } else {
            alert("Response = false");  
            }
        }
    );
}
);
```

Comment: what the problem is in `json_decode`?

Answer (score 0):

the structure for the .post function on jquery is:

```
jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

in this case, you are using the url, data and the success function, and in theory jquery should already know that the answer is a json answer and evaluate the answer to an object, but just to be sure change your code to add the json datatype:

```
$.post(
  $_interface,
  { option: 'login', userID: username, pwd: password },
  function(response){
    if (response) {
        // alert("Response = true");
        $.post(
            $_interface,
            { option: 'superGlobalValues', target: 'session' },
            function(data){
            alert(data);
                }
            );
        } else {
        alert("Response = false");  
        }
    }, "json"
);
```

and if that doesn't work, just evaluate the answer, so instead of doing

```
function(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

do something like

```
function(data) {
  my_json = eval(data);
  alert(my_json);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if magic_quotes_gpc and magic_quotes_runtime in your php.ini turned off (use search)
2. Also you can write in your .htaccess:

   ```
   php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 0
   php_flag magic_quotes_runtime 0
   ```
3. You can use php function stripslashes($string) on your requested data.

Answer (score -1):

[jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) object have param dataType, which can be set to JSON and you will get correct parsed response as object.
Example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data){ //data contains parsed response, try to console.log this },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: .post is a high level function that internsly use .ajax and ehete u can also put the dataType to be expected. No need to do a low level call to .ajax, using .post, .get and others is more pragmatic

Comment: @rorra - the question was very simple : How correctly get json response from server using jquery, but looks like you are trying to complicate easy things.

Answer (score -1):

Vadim is right or use var myObj = JSON.parse(data).

Comment: Why to use .ajax low level when u can usr .post? Also jquery is smart enough to autodetect the dsta, just in case i show him how to force jso datatype in .post function and as a last resource how to eval the string to convert it to a js object

Comment: @rorra - you know eval is evil?! JSON.parse is native JavaScript and transform a json-string into an object in json notation. Your example is just the short form of Vadims sample ;)

Comment: the eval is actually a pragmatic way to convert a string into json, promoted on the json home page: http://www.json.org/js.html
Is not evil because it will only execute the data that your server retrieve, and there is not reason to answer with anything other than a json response. It could be that someone could hack into your website, and then he can change the answer to be a url redirection to a dangerous website, but if someone hack into your website and update your source code, he can do a lot of dangerous stuff rather than updating the answer to be a url redirection instead of json data.